# How do I save and quit from Vim?

Tags: linux, vim

I'm trying to edit a my.cnf file on a Linux server and edited using vim. After doing my edits, I am unable to escape. I have tried exiting using the following methods:

- `q`
- `!q`
- `wq`
- `!wq`

None of these methods have worked. Upon exiting, it gives me the line:

```
shell return 127
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

If I do either of those suggestions, I go back to vim. Also, ctrl-c does not work. Please help. I need to end it with vim.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get an error 127 which means "invalid command" because when you type `:!q` it calls an external command: Here you're trying to execute the command `q` in your shell which doesn't exist.

To force quit the command is `:q!` but if `:wq` doesn't work maybe that means that you don't have the permissions to edit your file. If that's the case you should use `sudoedit` to edit your file.

Also for vim specific questions try to ask your question on [vi specific SE site](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) it is still in beta but pretty reactive.

Comment: Ahah don't feel dumb vim can be pretty disorienting when you're not used to it. If you whan a short tutorial to learn how to use the basic features look at the `vimtutor` command (it is in the repos of most of the common linux distribs) that's a good way to begin with vim.

Comment: Do you self a favor and do as @statox says run `vimtutor`, especially if you have to remote into *nix boxes. Sure you can use `nano` or `pico`, but `vi` is the unix standard and often set as the default `$EDITOR`. Learning basic Vi/Vim is a skill well worth having.

Comment: Peter is totally right, plus when you know how to use it (even just the basic features) you can really shorten the time you spend editing your files. (yeah I know that's a breaking news)